# Buddypress - List current user's profile information

Tags: loops, buddypress, members

I have successfully set up a Buddypress profile page that lists the current user's name and avatar at the top of the page. The issue is that the page also lists other members' information beneath the current user.

How do I change this to *only* list the current user's information and not anyone else's?

Here is a very simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
        <?php if ( bp_has_members( bp_ajax_querystring( 'members' ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

            <?php bp_member_avatar(); ?>
            <?php bp_member_name(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>          
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks!
Lauren

Answer (score 0):

I was able to single out only the current user by using the following:

```
<?php if ( bp_has_members( 'per_page=1' ) ) : ?>
```

I'm sure there are multiple ways to go about doing this, but this was the first solution I found.